# Software tools or libraries for dealing with temporal reasoning (visualization/representation).

Tags: logic, math-software

Temporal aspect of data with no doubts is an important characteristic for many software systems.

I'm interested if there are any tools/frameworks for dealing with temporal data for reasoning on it. I need it for writing a software application for visualization of temporal data to a user. The application will help a user to understand data from different sources in terms of time relations.

From the mathematical point of view, temporal reasoning maybe described using First-Order Logic (FOL), Modal or Reified Logic. Also, the reasoning in time maybe based on Point-based Logic, Interval logic, event or process logic - there are many flavours of logic which deal with the time.

So far, I found two frameworks (if it's possible to call them like this)which are potentially a start point for writing the application:

1. *OWL-Time* which is based on RDF format and gives a tool to a developer to manage time properties of , for example, a web service.
2. *ISO 19108 standard of Open Geospatial Consortium* - I think, also maybe a start point for developing the app.

As I understand, both standards propose using FOL and interval logic. Is there anything analogical but using, for example, fuzzy intervals or Modal logic instead FOL?

Thank you for your kind help.

Cheers.